# How do I implement semantic searching across multiple MongoDB models using NodeJS and Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose, backend

Apply Semantic Search on different models of MongoDB and integrate into a single Seach Bar: I have 3 Models:

Student: Scholar no., full name, dob, city, address, roll no., school register no.

School: School register no., School name, address, established date, BoardID

Board: BoardID, Board Name, director name, etc.

I am generating a report that contains the following columns: Scholar no, Full Name, DOB, School Name, and Board Name.

I have a Search bar, and I wish to apply a semantic search on all columns of the report.

for Eg. a user may choose to search a field by either name or scholar no, the result should be generated.

I have services like getStudentByfilter, getSchoolByFilter, and getBoardByFilter where the input parameter is filtered and these services fetch data from DB using findOne().

I am a beginner with this concept, any help will be greatly appreciated :)

in my controller I am doing this:

```
if (req.query && req.query.search) { 
    filter['$or'] = [{ name: { "$regex": req.query.search, "$options": "i" } }]; 
}
```

```
let studentIds= await studentService.getStudentByFilter(filter);
```

```
let stIds = [], stNames = []; 
if (studentIds&& studentIds.length > 0) 
{ studentIds.map((student) => { 
    stIds.push(student._id); 
    stNames.push(student.name); }); 
}
```

Service:

```
const getStudentByFilter = async (filter) => { let activestudents = await Student.find(filter).select({ scholar_id: 1, full_name: 1, dob: 1 }); return activestudents ; };
```

Comment: if u can conduct search on one model, why not perform 3 different searches in 3 different models, and send the result merging the list